# MySQL idle connections get reset every 10 mins

Tags: mysql

I have the idle connections (sleep state) get reset every 10 min even though I have **wait_timeout** set to 3 hours, with an error: Aborted connection - (Got an error reading communication packets)

The api is hosted on GCP.

Any idea how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see setup:

```
show variables like 'wait_timeout';
show variables like 'interactive_timeout';
```

MySQL indeed supports two different `wait_timeout` settings, one for regular connections and one for batch connections (processed in batch mode). The `wait_timeout` settings determine how long a connection remains open when it is not actively being used.

1. **`wait_timeout` for regular connections:** This setting applies to standard connections to MySQL. It determines how long a connection remains open when it's not actively in use. When the timeout is reached, the connection is terminated, and resources are released.
2. **`interactive_timeout` for batch connections:** This setting applies to batch connections that are processed in batch mode. It's similar to `wait_timeout`, but it is usually set to a longer duration because batch connections can often have longer periods of inactivity.

The difference is that `interactive_timeout` is typically set higher than `wait_timeout` to ensure that connections working in batch mode (e.g., bulk data loading) are not prematurely terminated.

In many MySQL installations, `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` are both set to 28800 seconds (8 hours) by default. This means that regular connections and batch connections can, by default, remain open for up to 8 hours if they are not actively used.

The use of `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` can be adjusted in specific use cases depending on the requirements of your application. However, it's important to note that the settings of `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` are global settings for the MySQL server and will affect all connections unless overridden in the connection string. This allows you to control timeouts for individual connections within your application when necessary.

Comment: The wait_timeout is already set to a high value but still the same issue.